# How to pause a function until a promise is returned?

Tags: angular

In my service, I am using `http` to get some data then return it as a promise.

I have a function like this

```
onClick(ID:number){
  this.myService.getSomeData(ID).then(response => this.myObject=response);
  //do something with myObject
}
```

However, I need to wait for the service to return the data before I can continue. I cannot call the service earlier because it depends on which option the user clicked.

I was thinking I could wrap it in `setTimeout`

```
onClick(ID:number){
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.myService.getSomeData(ID).then(response => this.myObject=response);
  }, 1000);
  //do something with myObject
}
```

but one second is just a guess and I might be wasting time or not have enough time. Is there a way to pause this function until that service returns information, ideally which will timeout after about five seconds (and if this happens, have it execute my handling code)? During this time, the user should not be able to do anything.

Comment: No no no no no. The `do something with myObject` goes **inside** the `then` branch. If your issue is that your template is trying to display something hanging off `myObject` you could try the `myObject?.prop` syntax. Depending on your use case, you might also want to look at the `async` pipe. Not allowing the user to do anything in the meantime is certainly not very user-friendly--she'll think the application has hung. However, you could turn off various UI features by doing things such as hiding UI elements based on whether `myObject` is defined, or rendering them conditionally.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice.